# wordpress cpanel redirects to unknown url

Tags: database, wordpress, server-side

I recently started receiving errors when trying to access my wordpress admin panel.
I don't know if its a server side error or a wordpress code error.

For example when visiting wordpress admin panel instead of the default url:

*http://www.yourwebsite.com/wp-admin/*

**It returns the following:**

*http://www.yourwebsite.com/KLllM/wp-admin/*

Can any of you explain why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

this might be because of any recent new theme? or a change in your website address made when a script ran from a theme or plugin. There can be several other reasons.
You might want to see these links.

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Hope this helps.